# How to multiply matrices in racket math/matrix?

Tags: matrix, racket

I looked into the documents, but merely found `matrix*`, <s>which is the entrywise multiplication action.</s> I think there ought to be an method for such a basic operation, but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matrix*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/matrix_arith.html#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Fmatrix..rkt%29._matrix%2A%29%29) does [Matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication):

```
#lang racket

(require math)
(require rackunit)

(define A (matrix ([1 2]
                   [3 4])))
(define C (matrix ([ 9 10 11]
                   [12 13 14])))

(check-equal? (matrix* A C)
              (array #[#[33 36 39] #[75 82 89]]))
```

[Verifying on wolfram alpha gives the same answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix+multiplication+of+%7B%7B1%2C+2%7D%2C+%7B3%2C+4%7D%7D+and+%7B%7B9%2C+10%2C+11%7D%2C+%7B12%2C+13%2C+14%7D%7D)